# MVC routing ambiguity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a psychical path: `Home/signUp.aspx`

and `Controller/HomeController.cs (related to Views/home/index.aspx)`

My routing is configured in the global.asax:

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

     //settings - manage toolbars
        routes.MapRoute("SettingsManageToolbars", "home/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

           routes.MapRoute(
               "Default",
                // Route name
               "toolbar/apps/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
                // Parameter defaults
                );
        }
```

When I surf to `home\signup.aspx`
I get a text page with "directory content"

How can I fix this routing?

Comment: In MVC you generally no longer use '.aspx' in your paths - the routing is there to turn a url into a call to a controller and action; which then will call a view - which is the .aspx or .ascx or whatever. I'm not sure you fully understand the purpose of MVC.  I'm also not sure I really understand your question.

Comment: Remove routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, routing does not handle requests that map to an existing physical file on the Web server. Routing does not handle the request even if it matches a defined pattern, such as {controller}/{action}/{id}.

If you want routing to handle all requests, even requests that point to files, you can override the default behavior by setting the **RouteExistingFiles** property of the **RouteCollection** object to true. When you set this value to true, all requests that match a defined pattern are handled by routing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#scenarios_when_routing_is_not_applied

Comment: Then why do I get to `directory content` page?

Answer (score 0):

Why is your home controller an aspx file? Try making it a HomeController.cs!

I'd suggest deleting your current controller and adding another via the context menu (right-click, Add)